# How to structure source code for embedded software

Tags: c, embedded, software-design

In trying to improve my embedded software skills (in procedural C, using C++11 features), I would like to learn what are optimal ways to structure/package source code for embedded systems.

I am working on building small scale systems (on a single microcontollers with 1-k4k RAM memory) without an RTOS. In order to be able to debug my software outside the target environment, I would like to emulate my system on my host computer.

I found out that it is standard to store information about  the processor and its internal devices (RAM, ROM, timers, etc.) in a [board support package](http://www.windriver.com/products/bsp_web/what_is_a_bsp.pdf).

But in my embedded project I also use other external devices (push buttons, LEDs, LCD, servos, IO multiplexer, etc.) that are connected using a PCB to the microcontroller. ***What is a standard way/standard name for a source code abstraction layer over an application specific PCB?***

I have searched in books on real-time system engineering (David Simon's *An Embedded Software Primer*, Jim Cooling's *Software Engineering for Real-Time Systems* and LaPlante's *Real-Time Systems: Design and Analysis*), but was unable to find a good reference for code structuring in embedded systems.

Comment: There is no language "C/C++". However, even for a single language, it is far too broad. Do some research on your own.

Comment: As you wrote, BSP refers to board, not to SoC/MPU. Anyway this question  is too broad

Comment: Thanks for your response, and my apologies if this (first) question is overly broad. Am I correct to see that I should also put all external-device related code in my BSP-package?

Comment: It also might be specific to the OS you are writing for. For example if you are writing for a custom embedded Linux, there is a very well defined structure.

Comment: Not to mention if you are targeting a microcontroller

Comment: He did precisely specify his OS, Eugene: none. There are common ways to organize such projects, but some are very chip-specific. For example, embedded ARM projects often use a standard called CMSIS, while others rely on libraries and tools from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wikipedia entry for BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_support_package), its purpose is to provide the board support (not just micro) required by a specific OS. So for the same hardware, different OS will likely require different BSPs, so I don't think that's the term you're after.

What you describe is what I would call a Hardware Abstraction Layer/HAL, and I believe this is a quite common name. In principle, this name could include the whole PCB, or only the MCU.

The important bit in a HAL is the Abstraction. A good abstraction will make it easy to replace, e.g. if you want to test code built on top of the HAL off-target. It will also make it easier to port that code to a different hardware platform.

I find many vendor-provided libraries fall short in this regard: You may call a function instead of modifying or reading registers directly, but the function call often corresponds directly to registers. That is, their library may hide behind the abstraction the compiler extensions necessary to interface with the chip, but not much else. Because of this, I tend to not use the vendor-provided library as a HAL, but may use it to implement one (or just access registers directly instead)

---

The optimal structure for a HAL depends on your design goals. You've stated one goal of being able to debug your application off-target. You've also stated that you don't plan to run an OS. You may be planning to support a single MCU or MCU family, or multiple MCUs from different vendors. You may be planning a single board design, or multiple bespoke boards based on a common platform. These will all affect the design choices in a HAL design.

---

I often work on projects that don't use an RTOS. Typically the hardware inherits some aspects from one or more older designs and has some new stuff. The new stuff can be small or big changes (including different MCU or MCU families).

In this context, my approach to HAL has developed into the following:

1. Define an API for each component in the HAL, (typically structs of pointers-to-function, such as `adc_driver_api_t`, `uart_driver_api_t`, `i2c_driver_api_t` etc.). These APIs do not use any chip/compiler extensions or includes, but typically adhere to a language standard (C89/C99).
2. The HAL for a given platform provides implementations for these, e.g.  `msp430_adc12_driver`, `msp430_adc10_driver`, `pic18_adc12_driver`, `avr_adc_driver` etc all implements the `adc_driver_api_t` interface using different peripherals available on the respective platforms. Each implementation expose a const global instance of the implemented driver in the implementation header file, e.g. (using C) `extern const adc_driver_api_t msp430_adc12_driver;`. These implementations use chip/compiler extensions or includes as required.
3. A component using the HAL to get ADC readings would be initialised with a `const adc_driver_api_t *` implementation and anything else the API requires (perhaps an adc channel). The component and the ADC driver implementation would both be initialised and connected together in the program initialisation, e.g. top of `main()`
4. I try keeping the HAL API lean. For instance, some peripherals may allow you to put a 12-bit result in the top 12 or bottom 12 bits of a 16-bit register. I would not allow for configuring this via the HAL API, but may provide a function to set this directly in the module that implements the HAL API, so in msp430_adc12_driver.h there may be a function `msp430_adc12_driver_set_result_alignment()` that can be called during system initialisation.

I find that this approach allows components to be built on top of the HAL in a hardware-independent way, so I can easily reuse components on different platforms. It also allows the components to be written, debugged and unit test the components off-target, with test doubles for the HAL.